# How to change default short date format to m/d/yyyy in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

Default is now d-mmmm. That means when I type 12/6 Excel prints 6-Dec. I would prefer 12/6/2021.

Language/Regional format data -settings in Windows do not change short date format in Excel as far as I know.

Is it possible to change **default** from d-mmmm to m/d/yyyy in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, this is not possible.

According to [Microsoft Community answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-change-default-short-date-format-to-mdyyyy/54cfc984-fd7e-4346-b507-afb442e38b22?messageId=ed0803ac-13d9-4cf9-b7bc-6eb6d70bf773) this is hardcoded into Excel.